# Facebook iframe has back button issue in Firefox and IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe

The facebook dynamic iFrame I have been working on which works fine in Chrome and Safari has an issue in internet explorer and Firefox where the iframe is displayed but displays again once the back button has been pressed.

The code below for the facebook iframe does not include the appId and redirect_uri which I left out.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {     
$('#initanchor').click(function(){

window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
FB.init({
                appId: '',
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                oauth:true,         
                status: true });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

                if (response.authResponse) {

  FB.ui ( { 
      method: 'send',  
      access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken, 
      redirect_uri:'',
      display: 'iframe',  
      show_error: 'true',  
      to: ''
  }); 

   } 

  });  

 };  


  (function(d){

     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;} 

    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true; 

    js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);

  }(document));



 }); 

 }); 

</script>
```

Comment: Interesting. Usually, clicking a link within an iframe places the frame content inside the browser history, so that clicking back navigates through the content of the iframe until you reach the first page of content.  In Facebook, this behavior is broken (only) for Chrome: pressing browser back or forward has no effect on the content of the iframe. I suspect that these problems are related.